# Ruby - no such file to load ERROR RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rspec

I'm trying to use rspec to run a spec file. However, when I run the command (bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb), I get an error saying:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load': no such file to load -- /Users/Home/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/spec/spec/00_hello_spec.rb (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load_spec_files'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load_spec_files'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `autorun'
from /usr/bin/rspec:23
```

I tried following the instructions of a few other SO answers such as including require 'rubygems.rb' at the top of the spec file and trying require_relative but it's a no go. I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.8, Ruby 1.8.7 and RubyGems 2.4.6.

My Ruby details:

```
    Homes-MacBook:~ Home$ which -a ruby
    /usr/bin/ruby
    Homes-MacBook:~ Home$ gem environment
    RubyGems Environment:
    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
    - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-       
    darwin10.0]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE:     
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
    - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Home/.gem/specs
    - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY:   
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/etc
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
    - GEM PATHS:
    - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
    - /Users/Home/.gem/ruby/1.8
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
   - GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   - REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
   - SHELL PATH:
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/X11/bin
   - /Users/Home/.rvm/bin
   Homes-MacBook:~ Home$ which gem
   /usr/bin/gem
```

Comment: Does the file `/Users/Home/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/spec/spec/00_hello_spec.rb` exist? Check to make sure you are executing the command from the right directory (try `cd ..`)

Comment: Wow, I just figured it out. I had an extra spec. So, my command should be "bundle exec rspec 00_hello_spec.rb" not "bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb"- thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Side note: You might want to upgrade your ruby version as well - 1.8.7 is ancient and won't work with many current gems.

Comment: Can I upgrade Ruby to the latest version even though I have OSX 10.6.8? When I download the file, I can't open it (says it's incompatible with the OS). Can I do it via curl or rvm or something else?

Comment: Not sure, but you can always try with rvm. Could be that the installer for the binary ruby is not compatible with 10.6.8 or it could be that you are missing some of the C header files.

Comment: why the heck in the world one would use 1.8.7?